# How can i get the actual controller in post method

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I have two controllers Project and Tag, both of which have a create view and get post methods.

From the Project create view I have the option to add a tag which opens a dialog with the tag create view.

When i add the tag it goes to the tag controller create post method at which point i want to be able to get the controller action that sent it there (in this case Project). I have seen the UrlReferer class, is there a better way to get the controller than that?

the reason i need this is i want to be able to do something like

```
            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                if (REFERER CONTROLLER != Tag Controller)
                {
                       return Json(new { Item = item, Success = true });
                }
                else 
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
             }
```

so basically if the dialog is in another controller then return a json of the new value otherwise return the index action

**Edit** ended up using this idea again. went for

```
if (Url.IsLocalUrl(Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri) && !String.Equals(Request.UrlReferrer.LocalPath.TrimEnd('/'), Url.Action("Index"), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    return Json(new { Item = item, Success = true, Field = String.Format("#Selected{0}s", ControllerName) });
}
return Json(new { Success = true, Field = "#mainContent", Url = Url.Action("Index") });
```

Comment: @ChristoferEliasson basically the reason was i want the json of the single to update a dropdownlist if its not the list view. otherwise i want the index view refreshed with a partial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a few options:

1. You can look at the referring URL (there's no point in taking the referring URL string, parsing out the controller name and then creating an instance of your controller class unless you need access to some sort of method or property in the class; I would just look at the string).
2. You can include a hidden input which includes the controller name.
3. You could store a value in session (this seems like overkill; remember, a cookie will be created for this) to remember what page the user came from.

Options 1 and 2 *could* be tampered with before your server receives the value.

Comment: I have ended up appending a boolean from the js call for whether or not it is the tag controller but a good summary of the options